# Unable to use wifi card after putting it into monitor mode

Tags: debian, security, wifi, ifconfig, airmon-ng

I'm trying to monitor 802.11 Reauthentication requests and responses made from the DS to the STA.

The problem is when using airmon-ng to put the card into monitor mode, the interface is no longer available in the network manager, so I'm unable to connect to my AP to monitor the requests.

Any ideas how to resolve this?